# INSERT copying values from another row, but not all values

Tags: database, postgresql

I have a table `project_data` with data from a project. It has a column `project_id` that references the table `projects`.

I want to implement a function that copies a project into a new one. For that, I need to copy all entries of `project_data` with respective `project_id` into new rows. However, the field `project_id` of the new rows should be different from the original copied rows, because they must reference the new `project_id`.

Example:

| id | project_id | random_field | random_field2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | A | B1 |
| 2 | 25 | D | E2 |

Upon copying the project of id = 12, the table becomes:

| id | project_id | random_field | random_field2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12 | A | B1 |
| 2 | 25 | D | E2 |
| 3 | 30 | A | B1 |

How to do that?

EDIT: I tried

```
INSERT INTO project_data (random_field, ramdom_field2)
              SELECT random_field, ramdom_field2 from project_data
```

But I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO project_data (project_id, random_field, random_field2)
              SELECT 30, random_field, random_field2 from project_data
              WHERE project_id = 12;
```

Then if that does what you want `COMMIT;` otherwise `ROLLBACK;`